# New column in tibble with the sum of the unique previous elements of a column

Tags: r, sum, dplyr, tibble

My tibble :

```
   cat    long         
   <chr>  <int>
 1 A      6842
 2 B      5750
 3 B      5750
 4 C      4860
 5 D      7284
 6 D      7284
 7 D      7284
```

I try to have in the new column sum of the previous elements in `long`. Like this :

```
   cat    long   cumu         
   <chr>  <int>  <int>
 1 A      6842   6842
 2 B      5750   12592
 3 B      5750   12592
 4 C      4860   17452   
 5 D      7284   24736
 6 D      7284   24736
 7 D      7284   24736
```

I've tried this :

```r
data <- data_tb %>%
  group_by(cat)
  mutate(cumu = ifelse(row_number() != 1, sum(unique(long[1:row_number()])), long))
```

But I don't get the expected column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` and `duplicated` :

```
transform(df, cumu = cumsum(long * +(!duplicated(long))))
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(long = cumsum(long * +(!duplicated(long))))

#  cat  long
#1   A  6842
#2   B 12592
#3   B 12592
#4   C 17452
#5   D 24736
#6   D 24736
#7   D 24736
```

`+(!duplicated(long))` would give 1 to all the unique values and 0 to duplicated values.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! In  `cumsum(long * +(!duplicated(long)))` what's the meaning of `*` and `+` ?

Comment: `!duplicated(long)` returns logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`), using `+` at the beginning we convert it to integer. So `TRUE` is changed to 1 whereas `FALSE` to 0 and we multiply this 1/0 value to `long`. So all duplicated values are turned to 0 and unique values stay as it is and finally we take cumulative sum of only unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea via base R is to do the `cumsum` and replicate each value the length of each group, i.e.

```
rep(cumsum(unique(df$long)), aggregate(cat ~ long, df, length)$cat)
#[1]  6842 12592 12592 17452 24736 24736 24736
```